# why content get mixed in parallel function call in node.js

Tags: javascript

i have three existing function,which i dont want to change.

```
getA : function (ac, cb) { //ac is action context
    ac.models.get("Model").getRec(function(result) {
          //extract the result into data and do some operation
          data.rec.type = "A";
          if (typeof cb === "function") {
               template.A = data;
               responseRecieved++;
               cb (null, data);
          }
    }      
}

getB : function (ac, cb) { //ac is action context
    ac.models.get("Model").getRec(function(result) {
          //extract the result into data and do some operation
          data.rec.type = "B";
          if (typeof cb === "function") {
               template.B = data;
               responseRecieved++;
               cb (null, data);
          }
    }      
}
similarly getC is third function.
```

Now, client send an array of type in query params like `?type="A","B"`. Now, i will call getA() and getB() parallely and send the collective data back. The need is even though getA() fail and getB() pass, in this case too we will send data getB() back.

because of this reason, i can not use `asynch.parallel` which will return result immediately after getting an error in any function call.

So, My approach is,
take an object "template" and var responseRecieved = 0, and in each function when it response ready update these.

```
getAll : function (ac) {
   var recObj = {
                "A" : self.getA,
                "B" : self.getB,
                "C" : self.getC
            }, essentialObj = { //this pA / pB/ pC should be there respectively for A / B/ C in query params, otherwise we return. 
                "A" : pA, 
                "B" : pB,
                "C" : pC
            }, 

       type = decodeURIComponent(ac.params.getFromUrl("type")).split(",");
   for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        type[i] = JSON.parse(type[i]);
        if (recObj.hasOwnProperty(type[i])) {
             if (essentialObj[type[i]]) {
                 recObj[type[i]](ac, function (res){
                   if (responseRecieved === type.length) {
                     response.template = template;
                     ac.done(response, 'json');
                   }
                 });
             }
       }
}
```

When I get response after calling getAll(), A has some data of type "B".

```
A : {
  //some data
  rec.type = "B", //and other of type "A", this should not mixed up.
}
```

similarly for "B".

I dont know the reason why they mixed up. I am not modifying type anywhere. Also, i getting one jshint error, don't write function in loop. How can i move this `recObj[type[i]]()` function outside of loop.

Why type mixed up in response and How to avoid this ??

Comment: for the better way: can you use jQuery, or any other library, or just plain javascript?

Comment: doesn't `data` declared global ? about `don't write function in loop` - just declare a function outside a loop and call it.

Comment: to make it better try to use promises.

Comment: no data is local to function

Comment: so, better please make more focused example, that can reproduce problem.